# What is the best way to save and load large amounts of variables

Tags: xcode, swift, save, load, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to add a daily time sheet to my app where the user can save and load info across 18 different text fields. The problem is I what this to store the info for 2 years worth of days. I was going to use nsuserdefaults but I don't like the idea of declaring over 13000 variables and then writing if/else logic for everyday of the 2 years. Is there a smarter way to carry out this task?
Thanks

Comment: create a class of the 18 variables, create a dictionary store the class with the 18 variables and use the date as the key

Comment: You might consider using Core Data

Comment: You could keep doing the nsuserdefaults thing and force it to work for you, but things will only get harder and harder as you try to do more and more. This is the time to learn a database, it's an up-front investment of time that will really pay off in the long run.  There's core data and sqlite natively, and there are a handful of open source wrappers like [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) that greatly simplify things.